# Human relations for the future

Tags: human-condition, relations

If the future had lesser jobs for humans at all would (seems to head that way now like AI,partial self reliance vacuum cleaner, smart car)  the world be undoing what it just done?What do I mean?For a society functions like a body,the mouth,liver,pancreas and so on help digest or absorb food.Through roles like above,we develop realtionships (friends or foes).But robots would then take over most of the roles (assuming) ridding of our roles ie pushing each other away slightly (so close yet so far).
What are the potential problems? (age faster,depression so on)and Why? Has anyone raised these issues?

Comment: I am sure there are many books from many different subject areas. I can recommend “Eros and Civilization” by Herbert Marcuse (1956? or 1957, can’t remember). We were really already dealing with this problem before AI came along. Now this time in America was relatively affluent, the late 1950s.  We don’t know if this will continue into the future.

Comment: A concept here to note is the death instinct which can get activated with free time. Free time allowed by a guaranteed income. That is the robots, assuming the radically increase productivity, could allow more free time. Here is an article I have not read, but it looks like it may serve as an introduction. https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.2304/pfie.2006.4.1.18

Comment: (Unfortunately, I see the writer of the article throws Lacan into the mix, so that you can focus on Freud, here is the Wikipedia for the death drive:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_drive ).

Comment: Only psychological problems?